# Retina/high-DPI custom cursor in Java?

Tags: java, retina-display, hdpi, custom-cursor, highdpi

Is there any way to support high-resolution displays for Java custom cursors? The usual method seems to be using `Toolkit`:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(cursorImage, new Point(), "customCursor");
```

However, there is very little control over the cursor itself. Is there some method to do this which supports high-DPI displays, or will I need to hide the cursor and paint it manually?